# Why does my website only load after a refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, http

My web page takes minutes to load when I use incognito mode, however, when I reenter the same URL it loads in a couple of seconds.

On the first attempt, there is nothing down the bottom of my browser that suggests it is attempting to connect to the server, but on refresh it shows:

- connecting to *domain*.com
- performing TLS handshake etc..

Does anyone know why this is happening when the website files haven't been cached?

Here is my HTML head tag for reference, like I said on refresh the browser gives all HTTP responses within a couple of seconds:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description"
          content="{% block meta_description %}{% endblock %}">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/vendor/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/main.css') }}">

      <script type="text/javascript"> (function() { var css = document.createElement('link'); css.href = 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css'; css.rel = 'stylesheet'; css.type = 'text/css'; document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(css); })(); </script>

      <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/vendor/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker.4.13.30.min.css') }}">
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-lZFHibXzMHo3GGeehn1hudTAP3Sc0uKXBXAzHX1sjtk="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

    {% if config['ANALYTICS_GOOGLE_UA'] %}
      <script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        ga('create', "{{ config['ANALYTICS_GOOGLE_UA'] }}", 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
      </script>
    {% endif %}
  </head>
```

Here are my web page performance results from Pingdom, which doesn't show any resources taking too long to load:
[image]

Comment: Can you share your website URL?

Comment: @shaochuancs www.custodian.fund :)

Comment: I've tried visiting your website, but it loads pretty fast :)